# Работа со списком при помощи Future

Tags: scala

Имеется список из 5000 элементов. Хочу распараллелить процесс обработки списка через Future.
Один из вариантов, который я пробовал - это выполнение через Future в каждой итерации.
В качестве ExecutorContext я использовал fixedThreadPool(10).
Код вида

```
    val list = List("Ivan", "Sergey", "Victor")
    for(name <- list) {
      Future { //do something with name }
    }
```

обрабатывает не корректно.
При попытке добавить каждый name а базу - добавляется малая часть всего списка.
Вероятно, это происходит из-за того, что я не дожидаюсь выполнения Future.
Почему так происходит и как правильно распараллелить работу над списком?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Верно, `Future` у тебя создаются и выполняются в отдельном потоке. Нужен `Await` который будет ждать их в основном потоке.

```
val list = List("Ivan", "Sergey", "Victor")

import scala.concurrent.{Await, ExecutionContext, Future}
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
```

Создаём отельный пул потоков, специально для нашего списка:

```
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10)
val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(pool)
```

Тут мы проходимся по всему списку с именами и запускаем их, не дожидаясь завершения:

```
val seqOfFutures: List[Future[Unit]] = list.map { name =>
  Future { /* do something with name */ }(context)
}
```

Создаём ещё один `Future` который будет ждать весь список:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

val sequenceFuture: Future[List[Unit]] = Future.sequence(seqOfFutures)
```

И именно этот один `Future` будем ждать мы:

```
Await.result(sequenceFuture, Duration.Inf)
pool.shutdown()
```

---

[English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49924941/how-to-control-the-concurrency-of-future-sequence-in-scala)

Comment: А Await является целевым способом ожидания завершения выполнения Future или можно воспользоваться комбинаторами (map, flatMap, etc)?

Comment: Из основного потока - только `Await`, следовательно в программе `Await` использовать желательно не больше одного раза, в самом конце, чтоб программа не закрылась. С помощью `map`, `flatMap` и т.п., наоборот создаются новые `Future`, т.е. их тоже придётся ждать ещё.